# Is there a system event when a process is created?

Tags: windows, events, rust, process

Im writing an application in Rust that checks for certain processes. I know it's possible to get a list of running processes, but i rather not create an infinite loop to poll them.

Is there an event that gets triggered when a process is started?

Comment: This depends on your operating system. What OS are you on? The answer is unlikely to be specific to Rust.

Comment: Is the process you are monitoring for under your control? Will it create files in a known location you can monitor for instead? At least on Linux, it's a lot easier to monitor for filesystem changes than for processes.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Im using Windows. How would i check if for example Atom or Notepad is started? Does Windows create any files when a process is being started?

Comment: Sorry, I've got no clue about Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust can't do anything that the OS doesn't already provide, and Rust doesn't have its own runtime, so you can just use whatever the OS offers.

When there isn't already a crate for some thing, the problem boils down to: **How would you do that in C?** Find answer to that, and then use Rust's FFI (or some lower-level sys crate like [`winapi`](//lib.rs/winapi) to call that.